# Change font color in flextable in R

Tags: powerpoint, flextable, officer, reporters

Ciao,
I have some trouble in changing font color in my flextable.

The R version is 3.5.2

I am working on this object since I have to add the table on a pptx presentation and to do this I will of course use officer package. Let me show you a dummy code and the output:

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)

ppt <- read_pptx()
ppt <- add_slide( ppt,  layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")
ppt <- ph_with_text(ppt, "Title whatever", type = "title")   

df = head(mtcars)
ft = flextable(df)
ft <- bg(ft, i = 1, bg = "#FF0000", part = "body")
ft <- bg(ft, i = 1, bg = "#FF0000", part = "header")

ft <- fontsize(ft, i = 1, size = 15, part = "body")
ft <- fontsize(ft, i = 1, size = 20, part = "header")

ft <- color(ft, i = 1, color = "#FFFFFF", part = "body")
ft <- color(ft, i = 1, color = "white", part = "header")  

ft <- font(ft, i = 1, fontname = "Consolas", part = "header")

ft <- autofit(ft)    
ppt <- ph_with_flextable(ppt, ft)

if(file.exists("prova.pptx"))
  file.remove("prova.pptx")
print(x = ppt, target = "prova.pptx")
```

As you can see I apply to the table a lot of formatting functions but I've noticed that the only one that fails is the "color" function.

[image]

The header and the first line of the table should be white. Notice that I've tried to assign to the "color" parameter both values "white" and "#FFFFFF" but in both case it does not work.

It is even more wierd considering that all other settings have been successfully applied.

> What I am missing about **color** function from flextable package? Have you noticed the same issue (bug) ?

Thanks,

Ciao

AM

Comment: the version I submitted to CRAN last week contained a bug that is fixed in the github repo - I will resubmit to CRAN today

Comment: Thx @David Gohel, you are my hero

Comment: no, you! That's what happened when issues are well described and reproducible :) You can understand and reply very quickly!